# How to get each value from a comma separated string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Lets consider I have a string called

```
string s = "jpeg, jpg, gif, png";
```

So from this I need to get each one like, I can assign each extension to one var variable
such as

```
var a = jpeg
var b = jpg
var c = gif
var d = png
```

Same way if I will add more extensions to the string then accordingly I will have to get all with same var variable.

Comment: You copy/pasted the same stuff between all the answers, next time try to build a better question. Remember that this could help others that have the same problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All you have to do is to use the javascript `split` method-

```js
$(function(){
    var s = "jpeg, jpg, gif, png";
    var match = s.split(', ')
    console.log(match)
    for (var a in match)
    {
        var variable = match[a]
        console.log(variable)
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But actually I want to achieve a target as explained below.

`function onUploadClick1(){
    var eachFileSize = '<%=EachFileSize %>';
    if (fileUpload.value.length > 0) {
        var ext = getExt(filename);
        var s = '<%=AllowedExtensions %>';
        var match = s.split(', ')
        for (var ext in match){
            onUploadClick();
        }
    }
}`

Here I am using this function. So what I need is if the selected files extension will match with supplied extensions then it will allow or else dont allow.

Comment: First : why is the allowedExtensions a string. It'd be much more nice to have it directly written as a javascript array.
If you use jQuery, you can have the `jQuery.inArray(ext, s.split(', '))` And if you don't have jQuery, you should find several inArray function thanks to Google, like [this one](http://phpjs.org/functions/in_array:432)

Comment: I've just said it, I think... I'm sorry not to be clear enough.
I've [updated the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zMHn5/1/) with more explanations

Answer (score 1):

try `Split` function of javascript will do your task

```
string s = "jpeg, jpg, gif, png"; 
var arraylist = s.Split(", ") ;
```

**point to Note :** this provide you list of string i.e array of split string.......

Comment: Thanks for your response. But actually I want to achieve a target as explained below.

`function onUploadClick1(){
    var eachFileSize = '<%=EachFileSize %>';
    if (fileUpload.value.length > 0) {
        var ext = getExt(filename);
        var s = '<%=AllowedExtensions %>';
        var match = s.split(', ')
        for (var ext in match){
            onUploadClick();
        }
    }
}`

Here I am using this function. So what I need is if the selected files extension will match with supplied extensions then it will allow or else dont allow.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array with the [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split) method:

```
"jpeg, jpg, gif, png".split(', ');
```

You can then loop over it to get the individual values.

Assigning the values in it to individual variables is, frankly, insane, but you could play with [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But actually I want to achieve a target as explained below.

`function onUploadClick1(){
    var eachFileSize = '<%=EachFileSize %>';
    if (fileUpload.value.length > 0) {
        var ext = getExt(filename);
        var s = '<%=AllowedExtensions %>';
        var match = s.split(', ')
        for (var ext in match){
            onUploadClick();
        }
    }
}`

Here I am using this function. So what I need is if the selected files extension will match with supplied extensions then it will allow or else dont allow.

Comment: Why not ask a new question instead of adding a completely new requirement to the existing one?

Comment: where art thou semicolons?

Answer (score 0):

[s.Split(", ")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split) should work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But actually I want to achieve a target as explained below.

`function onUploadClick1(){
    var eachFileSize = '<%=EachFileSize %>';
    if (fileUpload.value.length > 0) {
        var ext = getExt(filename);
        var s = '<%=AllowedExtensions %>';
        var match = s.split(', ')
        for (var ext in match){
            onUploadClick();
        }
    }
}`

Here I am using this function. So what I need is if the selected files extension will match with supplied extensions then it will allow or else dont allow.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split`:

```
var list = s.split(', ');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But actually I want to achieve a target as explained below.

`function onUploadClick1(){
    var eachFileSize = '<%=EachFileSize %>';
    if (fileUpload.value.length > 0) {
        var ext = getExt(filename);
        var s = '<%=AllowedExtensions %>';
        var match = s.split(', ')
        for (var ext in match){
            onUploadClick();
        }
    }
}`

Here I am using this function. So what I need is if the selected files extension will match with supplied extensions then it will allow or else dont allow.

Answer (score 0):

just do:

```
var arr = s.split(", ");
```

then you have an array of the values, iterate over that and do what ever

Comment: Thanks for your response. But actually I want to achieve a target as explained below.

`function onUploadClick1(){
    var eachFileSize = '<%=EachFileSize %>';
    if (fileUpload.value.length > 0) {
        var ext = getExt(filename);
        var s = '<%=AllowedExtensions %>';
        var match = s.split(', ')
        for (var ext in match){
            onUploadClick();
        }
    }
}`

Here I am using this function. So what I need is if the selected files extension will match with supplied extensions then it will allow or else dont allow.

Answer (score 0):

lets consider you have a string like

```
**var** = s = "jpeg, jpg, gif, png";
```

split it with ',' and you have an array

```
var strArray = s.split(',')​
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But actually I want to achieve a target as explained below.

`function onUploadClick1(){
    var eachFileSize = '<%=EachFileSize %>';
    if (fileUpload.value.length > 0) {
        var ext = getExt(filename);
        var s = '<%=AllowedExtensions %>';
        var match = s.split(', ')
        for (var ext in match){
            onUploadClick();
        }
    }
}`

Here I am using this function. So what I need is if the selected files extension will match with supplied extensions then it will allow or else dont allow.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a comma delimited string, which was the question, there's no need to split.

In this case **response** is a json object returned from a service via an ajax call. The json contains an element called tags which is itself a collection object which I put in a javaScript array.

```
var metaTags = new Array();
metaTags = response.Tags;

for (var tag in metaTags) {
  $("#divTagContainer").append("<div class='divTagItem'>" + metaTags[tag] + "</div>");
};
```